# Getting "java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: " in java code

Tags: java

I am trying to validate the linkedIn profile of 100K person and wrote a dummy code but its giving "java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://www.linkedin.com/in/test.user"

I have tried setting different setRequestProperty but not working.

public static void main(final String[] args) {

```
    String output = "";
    int TIMEOUT_VALUE = 99999999;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String urlEndPoint = "";
    String authUser = "";
    String authPwd = "";
    try {
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        urlEndPoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/test.user";
        authUser = "linkedin-username";
        authPwd = "linkedin-password";
        URL url = new URL(urlEndPoint);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("username", authUser);
        conn.setRequestProperty("password", authPwd);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Keep-Alive", "header");
        conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE);
        conn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,mt;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,br");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.linkedin.com");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36");
        conn.setRequestProperty("http.agent", "Chrome/71.0.3578.80 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        String userPassword = authUser + ":" + authPwd;
        String encoding = Base64Encoder.encode(userPassword);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.flush();
        conn.connect();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
        if (os != null) {
            os.close();
        }

        long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        //this.logger.error("Error occurred during processPartyTerrRelationship ", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //this.logger.error("Error occurred during processPartyTerrRelationship ", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //this.logger.error("Error occurred during processPartyTerrRelationship ", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {

                conn.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //this.logger.error("Error occurred during processPartyTerrRelationship ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //logger.info("processPartyTerrRelationship called ends");

}
```

The outcode of above code is :

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://www.linkedin.com/in/test.user
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at ValidateLinkedInProfiles.main(ValidateLinkedInProfiles.java:57)
```

Comment: 403 means that you are not allowed to view the site

Comment: Some sites don't allow accessing their web frontends with coded programs. Ususally this can be dodged by setting a User-Agent that looks like a browser's, but this is what you've already done. Maybe remove the http.agent header or play with different User-Agent values.

Comment: Removing the user-agent didn't help and still the same issue. Tried with other values too.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP 403 is a standard HTTP status code communicated to clients by an HTTP server to indicate that the server understood the request, but will not fulfill it. There are a number of sub-status error codes that provide a more specific reason for responding with the 403 status code.`

You either do not have access to the site(try logging in from a browser and try to run the script from the same browser, if your access is shared across different tabs of the same browser that is also fine, but make sure you're authorized) or the request to the link contains sensitive information which the site doesn't want to share.

Comment: I am able to access the site but for the lists of profile I have this code isnt returning for any of them.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTTP error code 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) is an error related to the authorization to the requested resource:

> HTTP 403 provides a distinct error case from HTTP 401; while HTTP 401 is returned when the client has not authenticated, and implies that a successful response may be returned following valid authentication, **HTTP 403 is returned when the client is not permitted access to the resource** for some reason besides authentication

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand how you're working. The LinkedIn link requires login. But you indeed need to debug it somehow and need a raw real output to the server with the correct one otherwise you will not complete it. If you have Java example program, see if they or you have a typo, but again without screenshot or text from LinkedIn I cannot debug it. Maybe try to add the examples and I will try to help you (just make me login with my public profile to other places). Also make sure there is your real password and your user account in the correct fields of course (`authUsr`,`authPwd` shall not be copy paste unlike everything else).

Comment: Vitali- Thanks. with the credentials(real one which i am using in code), I am able to access the linkedIn profile of the person. One sample could be this profile : https://in.linkedin.com/in/anil-kumar-jaguri-39914a168

Comment: Let me tell you what I would do. Normally you run wireshark/telnet/postman/chrome debugger, but here just do it step by step. You have many fields, that's all. That's the whole problem, so just break it down Login, once it works, add fields and in the end work out the post request. Roger that?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 403 is a legitimate response from a server. So the behavior is valid. However, I would recommend to use some HTTP client utility rather then writing your own code to make Http request. This will reduce the chance of a problem caused by your own code. As some Http clients I would suggest [Apache Http Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)  or [OK Http client](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/okhttp-example-rest-client) or MgntUtils Http Client (see MgntUtils HttpClient javadoc [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html), Full MgntUtils library on github is [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) and Maven repository is [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar)). 
Disclaimer: MgntUtils library is written by me